# scope of 'this' for a javascript onclick event

Tags: javascript, dojo, this

I am trying to access a function using `this` for a javascript `onclick` event. Currently i can only return the dom node using `this`. Is it possible to expand the scope outside of this dom node? I would like to call the function `toggleLayer`. Using dojo 1.7+

```
toggleLayer: function(){
  console.log('toggled layer!!!');
},

_init: function() {
  this.domNode.innerHTML = 'Click <a href="#"onclick="this.toggleLayer()">Here</a> to toggle layer';
}
```

EDIT - Here is the solution I came up with from Quentins answer:

```
toggleLayer: function() {
  console.log('toggled layer!!!');
},

_init: function() {
  this.domNode.innerHTML = ''; // Erase existing content
  this.domNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Click '));
  var link = document.createElement('a'); 
  link.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Here'));
  link.href = "#";
  link.addEventListener('click', this.toggleLayer.bind(this));
  this.domNode.appendChild(link);
  this.domNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' to toggle layer'));

}
```

Comment: It's possible, but not by `onclick` attribute. Use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead, in conjunction with  `bind`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in this case. You're generating DOM by creating a string and then converting it. The function you make from the string will have no connection to the scope you are in at all.

Use proper DOM instead.

```
this.domNode.innerHTML = ""; // Erase existing content
this.domNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Click "));
var button = document.createElement("button"); // Don't use links to the top fo the page for this
button.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Here"));
button.addEventListener("click", this.toggleLayer.bind(this));
this.domNode.appendChild(button);
this.domNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" to toggle layer"));
```

Comment: That works great thank you. I was able to convert this example to use a link instead a button.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Dojo way' of binding a context to a function is by using `lang.hitch`:

> hitch() returns a function that will execute a given function in a given context.

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/lang.html#hitch

Here's how it's done with pure Dojo:

```
require([
    'dojo/_base/lang',
    'dojo/dom',
    'dojo/dom-construct',
    'dojo/on'
], function(
    lang,
    dom,
    domConstruct,
    on
) {

    function onClick () {
        console.log('Got clicked context: ', this)
    }

    var link = domConstruct.create('a', {
        textContent: 'Click me!',
        href: '#'
    }, dom.byId('my-div'));

    on(link, 'click', lang.hitch(this, onClick));  

});
```

Comment: thanks ill look into this if i decide to go pure Dojo!